# How do you extract bitmap subtitles to a standard image format using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I need to extract bitmap-based subtitles to a standard image format like PNG or BMP. Preserving transparency would be a bonus. I don't need to convert to text, and I don't want a subtitle-specific format.

Answer (score 2):

The key is using the overlay filter to embed the subtitles on a transparent or fixed-color background. Adjust the `size` and `rate` to match your input video.

### Transparent version

`ffmpeg -i my_video.mkv -f lavfi -i "color=size=1920x1080:rate=23.98:color=black@0.0,format=rgba" -filter_complex "[1:v][0:s]overlay,mpdecimate[out]" -map "[out]" -an -vsync vfr frames_%04d.png`

This means:

- `-i my_video.mkv`: Input filename
- `-f lavfi`: The next input is a [`libavfilter` graph specification](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi).
- `-i "color=size=1920x1080:rate=23.98:color=black@0.0,format=rgba"`: Produce a video stream that is 1080p with a 23.98 fps frame rate. The `@0.0` specifier indicates a fully-transparent color, which requires `format=rgba`.
- `-filter_complex "[1:v][0:s]overlay,mpdecimate[out]"`: Overlay the first subtitle stream in input source 0 (the original video) atop the first video stream in input source 1 (the `lavfi` output). Decimate the output frames by removing all duplicates. Output a stream named "out".
- `-map "[out]"`: Use the stream named "out" in the final output.
- `-an`: Audio is disabled.
- `-vsync vfr`: Drop frame timestamps so that each unique frame, in sequence, is output only once.
- `frames_%04d.png`: Output frames_0000.png where `0000` is an increasing number. If you expect more than 10000 unique frames, increase `%04d` to `%05d` for 5 digits, etc.

### Non-transparent version (much faster?)

If you can tolerate, or prefer, a non-transparent background, the process may run much faster. It goes 3-4x faster on my machine. Just remove the `@0.0,format=rgba` part.

`ffmpeg -i my_video.mkv -f lavfi -i "color=size=1920x1080:rate=23.98:color=black" -filter_complex "[1:v][0:s]overlay,mpdecimate[out]" -map "[out]" -an -vsync vfr frames_%04d.png`

### Output

You'll get a PNG for each frame of unique subtitle content, plus a frame of black/transparent in between. Maybe there's a way to filter out those blank frames, but for now I can handle that outside ffmpeg.

### Caution

If you add `-t` to limit the time of the extracted subtitles, be sure to add it twice: once after the `-i` for the input video and once after the `-i` for the black frames & subtitles. This will ensure that both streams terminate at the specified time; otherwise one stream will keep going for the full video duration.